# Custom font does not render correctly when using ShowText

Tags: xamarin.ios, core-graphics, truetype, custom-font

I have a custom view in which I am trying to draw text using a Windows font (calibri.ttf). However, I am getting different behaviour between using the `DrawString` & `ShowText` functions.

I have embedded the font as part of the app (added it to the *UIAppFonts* list & set it's build action to *Content*) and I all works fine when I use the `DrawString` method from my custom UIView e.g.

**Code**

```
public override void Draw (System.Drawing.RectangleF rect)
{
    base.Draw (rect);
    DrawString("Calibri font via DrawString", new RectangleF(10, 10, 100, 100), UIFont.FromName("Calibri", 16f));
}
```

**Result**

[image: Using Calibri font with DrawString]

However, if I attempt to draw the same text this time using `ShowText` it appears as if the font isn't encoding the text correctly, or the character mapping is wrong.

**Code**

```
public override void Draw (System.Drawing.RectangleF rect)
{
    base.Draw (rect);
    var ctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
    ctx.SelectFont("Calibri", 16f, MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGTextEncoding.FontSpecific);
    ctx.ShowTextAtPoint(10, 10, "Calibri font via ShowText using SelectFont");
}
```

**Result**

[image: Result using FontSpecific encoding and ShowTextAtPoint]

**UPDATE** - Here is what I get if I use `MacRoman` encoding instead of `FontSpecific`:

[image: Result using MacRoman encoding and ShowTextAtPoint]

I have also tried loading in the font manually and using that but then I get nothing at all, it's like it doesn't recognise the font e.g.

```
var fontPath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("calibri", "ttf");
var provider = new CGDataProvider(fontPath);
var font = CGFont.CreateFromProvider(provider);

var ctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
ctx.SetFont(font);
ctx.ShowTextAtPoint(10, 20, "Calibri font via ShowText using SetFont");
```

I know that `DrawString` is UIKit & `ShowText` is CG (Quartz) so I understand that there may be differences. However, from what I gathered the only difference with DrawString was it corrected the issue with the difference in Offset (CG being at the bottom left/UIKit being at the top left).

*NOTE - The underlying problem I have is I need to use this font to draw text onto a layer via a custom CALayerDelegate. I don't have access to the `DrawString` function from in there, therefore, the only way I can see to draw the text is via `ShowText`. Alternative solutions are welcome!*

Comment: @JC Fraid not (hence why the question is still open). I do think the issue is actually compatibility between Calibri font & iOS, however, still yet to be confirmed. I eventually reverted to using a similar pre-built font (Verdana).

Comment: I found a similar font to Calibri called CartoGothicStd. I had to convert from OTF to TTF but it works.

Answer (score 2):

This really looks like an encoding issue. Try using `CGTextEncoding.MacRoman` instead of `CGTextEncoding.FontSpecific` (even Arial wouldn't render, as expected, with FontSpecific).

**UPDATE Oct 12th**

a) your last code sample won't work because Apple doc specifically [states](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html) not to use `SetFont` and `ShowText` together. Quote follow:

> Quartz uses font data provided by the system to map each byte of the array through the encoding vector of the current font to obtain the glyph to display. Note that the font must have been set using CGContextSelectFont. Don’t use CGContextShowText in conjunction with CGContextSetFont.

b) the `CGTextEncoding.MacRoman` code works with several other iPhone-supplied fonts. I'm beginning to suspect it's something about the **Calibri.ttf** font itself that is not supported by iOS.

Comment: I tried both and from what I can remember when I used `CGTextEncoding.MacRoman` I just got a bunch of question marks displaying. I retry it and post the results.

Comment: Posted the result - as I suspected I do get back a question marks. I am in no doubt myself that it is an encoding issue, however, I don't know what UIKit is doing differently to CG. Could you shed some light on this?

Comment: Only tried with Arial so far, but I'll try to find your font (from a Windows VM) to duplicate the issue.

Comment: Brilliant thanks, you should find `Calibri.ttf` in the `C:\Windows\Fonts` folder on a Windows box.

Comment: +1 Thanks for investigating this. However, regarding using `SetFont` and `ShowText`.... how else do you set the font for `ShowText` as it doesn't allow you to specify which to use (like `DrawString` does).

Comment: From the quote/link `CGContextSelectFont` should be used. In MonoTouch that means using `SelectFont`, otherwise you have to work with *glyphs* (and that's no fun at all)

Comment: Ok so for `ShowText` you are restricted to using `SelectFont` (which is fine for my particular scenario). Just can't seem to figure out why `DrawString` works fine but `SelectFont`/`ShowText` combo doesn't. There must be something the UIKit is doing different...